# How to remove a layer from a packet in python using scapy

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, packet

How can i remove a layer from a packet in scapy 
lets say we have a packet that consist of the following layers `IPv6/IPv6ExtHdrRouting/ICMPv6EchoRequest`
i would like to remove the `IPv6ExtHdrRouting` layer so we are left with `IPv6/ICMPv6EchoRequest`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, scapy does not have a particular method for stripping layers but scapy's method `remove_payload()` can come handy in situations like this. What you can do is.

```
pkt=IPv6/IPv6ExtHdrRouting/ICMPv6EchoRequest
pkt2=pkt[ICMPv6EchoRequest]
pkt[IPv6].remove_payload()
pkt /=pkt2
```

Which will leave you with your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a [tool](https://github.com/x00itachi/modify-pcap-pkt-layers) that allows making changes to pcap layers. You can use it to remove any layer by simply providing its offsets.

e.g. To remove the Ethernet layer,

```
python3 modify_layers.py -i test.pcap -l "(0,14)"
```

Tool: https://github.com/x00itachi/modify-pcap-pkt-layers